# How to find related issues in a hierarchy

Tags: sql

I have a table that contains parent child relationships and I need to find all related issues.

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 6 |

I need to be able to identify all related issues, ideally I could return a new table that returns the following.

| Issue | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |

I'm currently using CTEs to try and solve this, but I'm running into circular reference issues and I'm not sure how to create a group number for each. Essentially, it is just tracing up and down different parents and each group does not have one central parent node which I think may be causing the issues.

Comment: What's the database? I think it can be done in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.